# How to get the timezone Name in c#.net for window application?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

In windows application, right now I am using `TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName.Trim()` to get the time zone name(say default timezone of system  be `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi)`.

But problem is when user change the timezone to other value `(UTC-5:00 Eastern time(US & Canada))`.

Now, windows application is trying to read the `TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName.Trim()`, it's  returning the old time zone name `((UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi)` instead of latest one `(UTC-5:00 Eatern time(US & Canada))`.

When we stop and run the application again, only that instance its giving the latest changed timezone by user.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: It's very hard to follow what you're doing, particularly without any code at all. It could be that you're just looking for `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`, but it would help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Users are working for other time zones so they are changing timezones oftenty.
 My application captures users login session(login time, logout time  and timezone at that instant) details and send to database
 So if user has changed the timezone in middle ,this application is not capturing the latest changed time zone.
 Instead,it(TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName.Trim() ) only holds the timezone name which is present at start of the application
 irrespective of any number of times  user changing the system timezone.

Comment: None of this is a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, or says whether you've tried using `ClearCachedData`. Also note that you should send the time zone *ID* rather than display name...

Comment: You use the `TimeZoneInfo.Id` property... it's as simple as that.

Comment: Well that's still not using the ID, is it? Does it solve your problem of not picking up the time zone changes though? (You can test that, as you have the code... I can't.)

Comment: Shall i use the below code like clearcache before getting time zone information.Its working for me.                                                     <!          TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
            string  tziLocal = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName;

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest you is to save events with

```
DateTime.UtcNow;
```

and when display change that time with

```
item.xxDate.ToLocalTime();
```

;)